# How to use Timer.scheduleAtFixedRate in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I am new in kotlin android development.
So I want to know how to use

```
inline fun Timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(
    delay: Long,
    period: Long,
    crossinline action: TimerTask.() -> Unit
): TimerTask
```

Means any example....

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try this

```
    Timer().schedule(object : TimerTask() {
        override fun run() {
            Log.e("NIlu_TAG","Hello World")
        }
    }, 3000)
```

Or this one

```
Timer().schedule(timerTask {
            Log.e("NIlu_TAG","Hello World")
        }, 3000)
```

Or this one

```
    Timer().scheduleAtFixedRate(object : TimerTask() {
        override fun run() {
            Log.e("NIlu_TAG","Hello World")
        }
    },2000,2)
```

Short answer

```
Timer().scheduleAtFixedRate(timerTask {
        Log.e("NIlu_TAG","Hello World")
    },2000,2)
```

Comment: Thanks but I want to know how to use above kontlin inline fun

Comment: @sandeepkolhal as theory says, you can schedule an action between the start of the previous task and the start of the next one, so you can notify, for example, a progress bar progression and cancels it when it finishes. You can accomplish this with Kotlin coroutines

Answer (score 3):

you can also do this:

```
val fixedRateTimer = fixedRateTimer(name = "hello-timer",
        initialDelay = 1000, period = 1000,daemon = true) {
        println("Hello")
    }
```

Comment: But how we start this. I have that in my viewModel and i want to start it from Activity.